# I am using dynamic routes in my next js website. But the pages accessing those files were unable to call event handlers

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am using files as [...slug].js but in those files onClick event or any event handler is not working. Only HTML is loading in live site. The catch is it is working fine in localhost

Comment: Could you please post any console errors

Comment: Could please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: There are no console errors.